# Launch Images vs Storyboards in iOS app development

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode-storyboard

I have been struggling lately to understand this new storyboard concept introduced in iOS 8.0.

#### Question 1

So far I have been using launch images, but now I got curios about storyboards as they seem to **remove the need of specifying multiple launch image files per supported screen**.

So, if my launch image consisted in a red background with a text (all in an image), all I have to do now is designing a ViewController with red background and a text in the middle?

Are those understandings correct?

#### Question 2

- If I use storyboards, should I stop using launch images?
- If so, just removing the `Images.xcassets` folder is enough? Or maybe leave the launch `LaunchImage` subdirectory empty as icons are still needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Q1: Basically, yes.
- Q2: You do not need to "remove" anything. This a target-level setting; specify a launch screen file instead of a launch images source:

[image]

Note that this is the default in a new project, so it's easy to try it out and see for yourself.

Comment: hmm... It's a bit confusing. I submitted two apps before supporting iOS 7 - 9 before but I did not set any launch screen file. I just set the launch screen file name to blank and I use asset catalog. Then my app wasn't rejected and is also working well.

Comment: @JLT I don't see what's confusing about that.

Answer (score 2):

As per [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)

> In iOS 8 and later, you can create a XIB or storyboard file instead of
>   a static launch image.

And

> If you also need to support earlier versions of iOS, you can continue
>   to supply static launch images in addition to a launch file.

1. Yes your understanding are right. Launch storyboard is replacement of launch images. And this was introduced in iOS8.
2. If you are targeting users before iOS8 you need both, the launch storyboard and launch images.